# AWS CLI - Moving files between different S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to move files between two S3 buckets in two different accounts using AWS CLI. I was able to successfully do a test copy of the files. Now my question is, is the scenario below possible through CLI?

Existing structure:

```
S3 => Videos(bucket) => ID(folder) => list of transcoded video files

S3 => Thumbnails(bucket) => ID(folder) => list of thumbnails
```

New Structure:

```
S3 => Company(bucket) => dev/prod(folder) => ID(folder) => Videos(folder) => list of transcoded video files

                                                        => Thumbnails(folder) => list of thumbnails
```

The ID folder will also have a Thumbnails(folder) => list of thumbnails

So basically combine both S3 buckets data into one bucket in the new structure. Is it possible to do this kind of copying using CLI?? If so, please guide me in that approach.

Comment: Does the `ID(folder)` have multiple values, or is it just one folder? That is, are there multiple folders with different IDs, each of which will contain a Videos and Thumbnails folder?

Comment: There will be multiple folders with different IDs and each will contain Videos and Thumbnails inside it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible in the AWS CLI, since it is not a simple source->destination copy.

You would either need to program your own solution (eg with a Python script) or what I sometimes do is **create an Excel spreadsheet** with a list of the source files and some formulates to calculate the destination.

The result is that you want to create a formula that says:

```
aws s3 sync s3://video-bucket/123/ s3://company-bucket/dev/123/videos/
aws s3 sync s3://thumbnails-bucket/123/ s3://company-bucket/dev/123/thumbnails/
```

The spreadsheet should do that for each ID in the source list.

Try it on a copy of IDs to see if it works. If it does, copy all the commands into a text file and execute it with the shell.

Comment: great thanks for the quick response.. will try it out

Comment: Do you mean two different accounts where you would need two different set of keys?

Comment: @John  followed your suggestion. Created formulae manually to generate test commands and once they worked, stored all the actual commands in a shell and it worked wonders. Thank you.